# rotated child object looking at Camera, using lookaAt() and worldToLocal() in Three.js

Tags: javascript, camera, rotation, position, three.js

I have a problem with the three.js build in lookAt() method.
I have a hirarchical Object structure like this

```
var obj1 = new THREE.Object3D();
obj1.position.x=200;
obj1.rotation.x=0.1;
scene.add(obj1);

var obj2 = new THREE.Object3D();
obj2.position.y=-400;
obj2.rotation.y=0.21;
obj1.add(obj2);

var obj3 = new THREE.Object3D();
obj3.position.z=-200;
obj3.rotation.x=0.1;
obj3.rotation.y=-0.1;
obj2.add(obj3);
```

When I call

```
obj1.lookAt(camera.position);
```

it's working fine, but when I call the method from a child object, like

```
obj3.lookAt(camera.position);
```

the rotation is wrong.

Since the rotation of the parent object seem to be the problem, I thought about converting the world-position of the camera to the local position of the object, but I didn't get it working corectly.

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
vector.setFromMatrixPosition( camera.matrixWorld );
obj3.lookAt( obj3.worldToLocal( vector ) );
```

any help would be great.

Comment: `Object3D.lookAt()` does not support objects with rotated and/or translated parent(s). There may be a work-around. Do any of your objects have non-uniform scale (i.e., `object.scale.set( 1, 2, 3 )` )?

Comment: There is no scale to the objects applied.

Comment: I cannot give you an "answer" because the following approach does not always work correctly, but here is the concept: `THREE.SceneUtils.detach( child, parent, scene ); child.lookAt( world_space_target.position ); THREE.SceneUtils.attach( child, scene, parent );` By stepping through with the debugger, you may get a clear understanding of the issues involved.

Answer (score 0):

Just add these prototypes, then instead of .lookAt(vector), use .lookAtWorld(vector)

```
THREE.Object3D.prototype.worldToLocal = function ( vector ) {
    if ( !this.__inverseMatrixWorld ) this.__inverseMatrixWorld = new THREE.Matrix4();
    return  vector.applyMatrix4( this.__inverseMatrixWorld.getInverse( this.matrixWorld ));
};


THREE.Object3D.prototype.lookAtWorld = function( vector ) {
   vector = vector.clone();
   this.parent.worldToLocal( vector );
   this.lookAt( vector );
};
```

Comment: (1) `lookAt()` uses the 'up' property to make sure the object remains upright. Your method fails to do that. (2) Avoid using `clone()`, since it calls `new`. Use a closure, instead, if you must.

Comment: @WestLangley what solution would you recommend?